# How to redraw objects on Canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I want to draw rectangles on Canvas and then do same thing but with bigger ones. My code is:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
for(var i=0;i<10000;i++){
  ctx.beginPath();
  var x = Math.random() * 1000;               
  var y = Math.random() * 1000;               
ctx.fillStyle = "rgb("+
Math.floor(Math.random()*256)+","+
Math.floor(Math.random()*256)+","+
Math.floor(Math.random()*256)+")";
ctx.fillRect(x,y,10,10);
}
```

After that i use function that will say me how long it took to finish the drwoing. And next is:

```
for(var i=0;i<10000;i++){
  ctx.beginPath();
  var x              = Math.random() * 1000;               // x coordinate
  var y              = Math.random() * 1000;               // y coordinate
//wypelnianie
ctx.fillStyle = "rgb("+
Math.floor(Math.random()*256)+","+
Math.floor(Math.random()*256)+","+
Math.floor(Math.random()*256)+")";
//rysowanie
ctx.fillRect(x,y,200,200);
ctx.closePath();
}
```

That does the same but rectangles are bigger. Math works fine because times are good (i tested them) but at first drowing it draws rectangles from second code and then it does it again. It should draw first small rectangles and then biger ones.

What i do wrong?? Maybe it cant be done on same canvas??

Comment: It first draws a bunch of small rectangles. It then draws larger ones. The larger ones cover most of the small rectangles. [Look at this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tushk/), I added a delay for the large rectangles so you can see what happens. They are both drawn, and I am not sure what else you had in mind. Your code seems to work as written.

Comment: Ohh... i am just stupid. I am realy thankful for your help.

Comment: I actually thought the box drawing was pretty interesting :) It produces a sort of industrial/modern look.

Comment: Well yeah, i work on a project that will test speed load of Canvas and SVG,i mean which is better. But when i done first drawing and look at it i tought that it is rly good looking with such simple effect :D 

ohh you should try simple lines, many its like pure art :D